# Update textarea with value of multiple input elements

Tags: jquery

This is a bit more complicated than the title says. I have 10 input elements the values of which I would like to copy to my textarea. Input field 1 is line 1, input field 2 is line 2, and so on.

I want to automatically fill out the textarea when the input fields are filled out. Text wrapping doesn't matter, so if input field 1's text is long, it may stretch to line 2 (because of text wrapping), but input field 2 should always be on a new line after input field 2. Get my point?

All of the input fields have same class, so it's easy (I guess). I just cannot wrap my head around it. I guess you can map it, and do something like this, but I'm not sure:

```
<input type="text" name="text[]" />
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the bigger picture?

Comment: Just collect all the values in a string and everytime you add a value you add "\n" before.

Comment: I'm creating a generator to generate text stuff, and I need people to input whatever they want in the input fields, which will be shown in the textarea afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said they all have the same class, so I'll call it "myClass".

```
var texts = [];
$('input.myClass').each(function () {
  texts.push($(this).val());
});
$('textarea').val(texts.join('\n'));
```

Comment: When I add that into my .keyup() function, the text gets added, but it won't work. jsfiddle explains it all: http://jsfiddle.net/ypLzpqkL/

Comment: Ah nevermind. I added the "texts" variable initialization into the keyup(). Thanks!